# Webflow Slider not working after wordpress installation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, timthumb

I'm working on a website and I have a slider list that I duplicate on the website. The html version works right but once I made the changes to Wordpress the second slider is not working.

The images are being loaded correctly and I am using timthumb in both slides. Actually, the function to load the list items is the same for both sliders list.

The link is below:
http://artflexeventos.com/pacotes/aereos/#hoteis

You have to click in a button (selecionar) in order to the second list of slides appear.

The error that I can see in the browser are:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mask' of undefined (Google Chrome)
TypeError: data is undefined (Firefox)
```

I have no idea why it works on the first slides but not in the second one.

Comment: You are loading webflow.js twice.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, but that was only a test. I fixed it and still not working...